# How to echo mysqli results in a div with an onclick for javascript function which contains another onclick for different javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysql, ajax

I can't seem to find out the correct way to write this script; can someone please point me in the right direction, or offer an alternate way.
I have looked but cannot find any relative examples.
I am pulling info from a database with php/mysqli and echoing it in prospective divs with an onclick pointing to a javascript function. This all works great. The problem I am having is the 'innerHTML' includes an onclick pointing to a javascript function also; this doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to have a document.getelementbyid('somthing').innerHTML that contains a function call? I am not sure if I asked that write. The code is below. Thanks for any help.

```
    <?php
    $sql50 = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result50 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql50);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result50) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result50)) {
    $videopath = $row["videopath"];
    $posterpath = $row["posterpath"];
    $user = $row["user"];
    echo "
    <div class='vidresponsive'><div class='vidgallery'>
    <img onclick='showplay(this)' data-id='$videopath' data-id1='$posterpath' data-id2='$user'
    data-id3=".$_SESSION["myspot"]." src='" . $row["posterpath"] . "' width='300px' height='160px' id='next' name='next'>
    <div class='viddesc'>" . $row["title"] . "</div></div></div>";
    echo "
    <script>
     function showplay(img) {
    var id= img.getAttribute('data-id');
    var id1= img.getAttribute('data-id1');
    var id2= img.getAttribute('data-id2');
    var id3= img.getAttribute('data-id3');
      document.getElementById('crab').style.display='none';
       document.getElementById('sticky').innerHTML = \"<div class='controls'>\
    <video style='width:60vw;' controls autoplay poster='\" + id1 + \"'>\
    <source src='\" + id + \"' type='video/mp4'>\
    </video>\
    <br><span id='saywhat' onclick='liking();' class='point'><i id='thumbing' class='fa fa-thumbs-up notlike'></i></span>\
    </div>\"
    }
    </script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there's nothing here.";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
    <div class="vidclearfix"></div>
    <script>
    var id2= img.getAttribute('data-id2');
    var id3= img.getAttribute('data-id3');
    function liking() {
     $.ajax({
       url:'actions/like.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            id2: id2, id3: id3
        }
    });
       document.getElementById('saywhat').innerHTML += "Thank You";
       document.getElementById("thumbing").classList.remove('notlike');
       document.getElementById("thumbing").classList.add('like');
    }
    </script>
```

I just can't seem to get the function 'liking' to work, it's like it's non-clickable and nothing happens when i do click it. A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

This has been updated now and works if anyone needs any of it for a reference.

Comment: Your PHP code definitelly can't compile but I guess you just incorrectly removed some of it before posting here. As per the `liking` function: what do you expect it to do? Try looking into the console (in most browsers Ctrl+F12) for errors.

Comment: I want the liking function to post the data to a page for php processing and then complete the 3 getelement by id actions. But it's like my script doesn't find the liking function or something. Forgot to put the first echo, updated now. thanks.

Comment: Does your page have the jquery library included? Also, as Martin asked, check your browser's web developer tools console for errors when you try to click.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with that while loop. It looks like its spitting out the same js script block over and over. How many times does that define showplay()? Look at your resulting html source to see just how many it has.

Comment: i have jquery library. added vars id2 and id3 above ajax and fixed the posting part also the 1st getelementbyid worked but not the 2nd two. I don't know if there is another way to attach the script to each result from the database.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I have it working now. I forgot the (plus sign) in my getdocumentbyid('saywhat'). I had '=' and should have been '+='. The code is updated and working now if anyone needs this sort of reference for anything. Thank you all again. Now how do I show this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the external script variables `id2` & `id3` needed to be defined.

```
    var id2= img.getAttribute('data-id2');
    var id3= img.getAttribute('data-id3');
```

Also the last `innerHTML` statement was missing the operator `+`.

```
    document.getElementById('saywhat').innerHTML += "Thank You";
```

The PHP is echoing a script `function showplay(img)`; this can be moved outside of the php and still work. If left inside of the PHP it will place the same script on the page as many times as there are results in the database; this script only needs to be included once and not multiple times.